# How to stop logging in django celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I want to stop logging my celery results from this command.

```
./manage.py celeryd --purge -l info  -f /tmp/celery_test.log -E
```

When I run my test I get all of this task succeded messages that I want to ignore as we don't do anything with it. I tried adding `CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True` iny my settings file but that didn't seem to work.

I know I could pass `ignore_result=True` for each task but I want this to be a global setting.

Comment: isn't the answer to this just turning Django logging off? Not a celery setting?

Answer (score 0):

add below in your settings.py or where you set your celery.

```
import logging
class RequestsConnectionFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return False
logging.getLogger('newrelic.lib.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool').addFilter(RequestsConnectionFilter())
```

Comment: added this to my setting.py file right next to my celery config info and it still was logging the results

Answer (score 0):

try this command

> Blockquote
>   /manage.py celeryd --purge -f /tmp/celery_test.log

Comment: That seems to do the trick with not writing anything to that file. Is the result being logged anywhere else though? My broker DB perhaps?